# Add spinner while new image gets loaded completely

Tags: javascript, image, spinner, loading, gif

The role of the script is to change image.jpg with newimage.gif and vice versa when clicked.
**Now i want to add a spinner while the newimage.gif loads.

Something like on 9gag.com/gif .**
Can someone help me please?

This is the code:
html

```
<img src="/image.jpg" id="pic" onclick="change()"/>
<a id="first" href="/newimage.gif" style="display:none;"></a>
<a id="second" href="/image.jpg" style="display:none;"></a>
```

javascript

```
function change(){
var imag = document.getElementById('pic').src;
var img = imag.slice(-3);
var img1 = document.getElementById('second').href;
var imag2 = document.getElementById('first').href;

if(img == 'gif') {
document.getElementById('pic').src=imag2;
//    here the newimage.gif changes to image.jpg 
} else {
//    here the image.jpg changes to newimage.gif
//    i think here should be the code that will display a spinner while the image.gif loads completely
document.getElementById('pic').src=img1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way might be to set the CSS `background-image` property of the images to a loading spinner graphic.

HTML:

```html
<img src="path/to/real/image.jpg" class="loading">
```

CSS:

```css
img.loading {
    background: transparent url(path/to/loading.gif) no-repeat scroll center center;
}
```

Once the actual image is downloaded, it covers up the "loading" animated GIF background image.

If you have GIFs or JPGs saved with Progressive display, you'll want to resave those images without that option so the real image is invisible until the full image is downloaded allowing your spinner graphic to show through in the meantime.

Comment: I want something that check's when image.gif is fully loaded after the image.jpg get's clicked and the function 'change' starts.

Comment: Hm. Your could switch the "pic" image's src to an invisible GIF or PNG, then apply the CSS and class to the IMG tag. Then immediately set the src to the new image.

Comment: I'm using this script in a page where are many gif images. If i wanted to preload all images i would use
<img id="first" href="/newimage.gif" style="display:none;"/> instead of <a id="first" href="/newimage.gif" style="display:none;"></a>.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload.
Images outside of viewport are not loaded until user scrolls to them, and you have the aboility to have a small image placeholder untill it's loaded...

I've actually used it here, on a testing site, some time ago: http://dev.thomaskile.me/?page=test-zone&module=Masonry.

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind of way, the only problem is that after the image.gif gets loaded the spinner still appears.

```
if(img == 'gif') {
document.getElementById('pic').src=imag2;
//    here the newimage.gif changes back to image.jpg 
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";    
} else {
document.getElementById('pic').src=img1;

var image = new Image();
image.src = document.getElementById('second').href;

var x = image.complete;
if(x) {
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none"; 
} else {
document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
}
}
}
```

This is here i use the script http://www.2lol.ro/load/poze_haioase_miscatoare/20?ref=stk

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this site](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js) for a configurable spinner without additional graphics that can be attached to any dom element ? starting / stopping the spinner boils down to 2 js function calls.

the code comes under the mit license, the minified js standalone file takes 9kb, glue code for use as a jquery plugin is provided and there is a vml fallback for, err... steampunk browsers ;-).

i'm not affiliated in any way with code or author.